# PHP adding 2 variables not equaling to what its supposed to.(should be easy)

Tags: php, sql

I have a column on my database called "hrs_worked" (int), where it stores the amount of hrs I've put into a project.

What i want to happen within my app is that:
A. i enter in my current worked hours,
B. Extract the hrs recorded on the database,
C. Take A and add it to B,
D. Take this new number and record the added total (A above and B)to the database since that will be my new total hrs worked on any given project.

i take in the new hours(that i submitted via form) with:

```
$hrs = mysqli_real_escape_string($c2d, $_POST['hrs']);
```

I pull out the old hrs in the database via:

```
$pullOutHrsQS = "SELECT hrs_worked FROM tlm_accounts WHERE company_name = '$compName'";
$pullOutHrsDoIt = mysqli_query($c2d, $pullOutHrsQS);

$originalHrsSet = (int)mysqli_fetch_array($pullOutHrsDoIt);
```

I then add them via:

```
$hrs += $originalHrsSet;

or

$hrs = $hrs + $originalHrsSet;
```

Now, lets say that my old hrs are 10hrs worked, and my new hrs are 5hrs worked, I want to add these together via

```
$hrs += $originalHrsSet;

or

$hrs = $hrs + $originalHrsSet;
```

and instead of this resulting in 15hrs, it results in 6hrs. The math is always wrong.

I guess the question i am asking is " What am i doing wrong?! Am i missing something?"

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What's the value of `$originalHrsSet` when this line `$originalHrsSet = (int)mysqli_fetch_array($pullOutHrsDoIt);` is executed ?

Comment: The value of originalHrsSet is 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The better option would be to simply increment the field like this;

```
"UPDATE tlm_accounts SET hrs_worked = hrs_worked + '$hrs' WHERE company_name = '$compName'"
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is the optimal way.

Comment: lord knows i tried the above, in different ways and in the end.......ill use yours. i didnt even know i could do that! lol. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to SELECT data to UPDATE it (see Harry's answer), but for the record...

`mysqli_fetch_array` returns either an `array` or `null` but you are casting the return value to an `int`, so `$originalHrsSet` will always be either 1 or 0. Try this instead:

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($pullOutHrsDoIt);
$originalHrsSet = (int) $result[0];
```

Answer (score -2):

You do not need to select a whole array for a single value. Try using [mysqli_stmt_fetch](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) instead. Try using var_dump with the values you enter just to make sure they're what you expect.